# PostgreSQL function data types

Tags: postgresql, function, variables

How can I get the names and data types of all variables usedin in PostgreSQL functions? Going through prosrc column in pg_proc is one way. Is there a better one - some view which stores the information in a format that can be easily queried/filtered? PostgreSQL Version is 9.0.

Comment: Do you mean inside the functions, not just the parameters passed into them?

Comment: Yes, inside the functions. Arguments I can get using pg_get_function_arguments

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no in-built way in PostgreSQL to do this. The function body is stored as a text string without parsing it out into its components. You can - obviously - parse the variable names and data types out, but it requires some serious parsing.

For PL/pgSQL:

1. Read the first word (i.e. the first term separated by white-space from the next term); if it is `declare` then read on until the word `begin`.
2. Read the next word, this is the name of a variable.
3. Read everything until a comma `,` (separating one variable from another) or the word `begin` (end of variables), but ignore commas inside parentheses `()` as these are associated with an initialization of the variable or a data type modifier (such as `numeric(8, 2)`). This is the data type, with all of it's modifiers and any initialization.
4. From the text read in the previous step, extract everything up to `:=`. Everything before is the data type and any modifiers, everything after is an initial value.
5. Repeat from step 2 until you encounter the word `begin`.

There may be nested blocks in a single procedure, so you'd have to repeat this procedure for every block in the body.

For other languages like PL/Perl, PL/Tcl and PL/Python you'd have to parse variables according to that grammar. And then there are additional modules with procedural languages, like PL/R or PL/Sh, with yet again different grammar.

This is obviously not done with a simple `reg_exp` in a query, but would require some more advanced logical processing.

Comment: You can nest `DECLARE`/`BEGIN`/`END` blocks, so it could get considerably worse than this...

Comment: This also works only for PL/PgSQL functions. If there are PL/Perl, PL/R or other functions, their variable definitions are different.